# ModuleNotFound Error even though >>>import <module> works

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, sys

I recently installed the `pyinsane2` module using `pip install pyinsane2`. It was successfully installed. Running >>>import pyinsane2 in my python interpreter returns >>> wich I assume is a good sign, meaning that it was installed.
When I run my .py file in the command line using pathtodirectory> scan.py and hit enter, it gives me a `ModuleNotFound Error` in line 4, where it says import pyinsane2. I'm working with Python 3.6 on a windows 8 64-bit computer. I write my code with Notepad++.

When looking for answers in the web, it was suggested to look whether my python version and the  module are in the same directory.

I found out that my version of Python is in "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" using `sys.executable`(`where python` shows the same path). Then I found out where my modules are stored using `sys.path`. It showed "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pyinsane2-2.0.2-py3.6-win32.egg"(Why pyinsane2 didn't show up, even though the directory exists in site-packeges as well, I don't know) and now I am supposed to put both, python and the modules in one directory...

So finally, my question is, if that is the correct way to solve this? If yes, what do I have to move/do to get python and the modules in the same directory? 
If not, what would you suggest to fix the error of looking in the wrong directory for the modules?

P. S. I know there are many veriosn of this question out already, so feel free to mark as duplicate, but I couldn't find one that was using either windows python 3.6 or was not using ubuntu or anaconda...

Comment: show how you run your module. Print sys.executable from your module before the import. Compare results.

Comment: I don't understand, I installed the module using pip install pyinsane2, in the python intepreter I ran >>>import pyinsane2 and in my script it says import pyinsane2 (which gives me the ModuleNotFound error)

Comment: How do you run from  the command line? What is the result of `where python`?

Comment: in th cmd window it shows 'C:\Users\MyName>' And I type in pip install pyinsane2. Ths tells me tat the requiremtns are already satiesfied: pyinsane2 in C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages

Comment: How do you run  your script from the command line? And please provide information like that in the question itself, not in the comments

Comment: ´Where python´ shows me the same path as sys.executeable "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe"

Comment: I edited my question. Im runnning pathtodirectory> and then just scan.py and hit enter

Comment: Use the `assoc` and `ftype` programs to figure out which version of Python is run when you just do `scan.py`. In the meantime, run it as `python scan.py` since you know that's the right interpreter.

Comment: `python scan.py` worked! Thanks. I looked it up, but I couldn't tell what assoc and ftype would lead to in this scenario...

Comment: That's because you didn't run them. Type `help ftype` and `help assoc` for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

> So finally, my question is, if that is the correct way to solve this?

No, you don't move/copy anything like for fixing library imports.

I guess `pip install` (or any other `pip`) command by default installs it to the latest/compatible python2 version. If you want it in python3, `pip3` is the command. But I'm assuming you have python2 installed on your machine. Otherwise I don't think you will be facing such issues.

Comment: That's an awful lot of supposing for an authoritative answer.

Comment: That being said, the duplicate's answer seems to agree.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is python 3.6 since thats what it shows me when switching to the python intepreter. Running it with pip3 install pyinsane2 it tells me the requirement is already satisfied

Comment: Sorry @MadPhysicist, but what does your second comment mean? is there a duplicate which answers my question ?

Comment: @hccavs19. There might be. Could you provide the additional information I asked for?

Comment: I edited the question @MadPhysicist

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am pretty sure he has python2 installed, I used those words because the OP is using windows. I haven't done any programming on windows for years, and as far as I know windows (I'm far from being even close to an expert), it's not so reliable especially when it comes to open source software. I am yet to encounter a Linux machine without python2 and with python3, but that may be because of my ignorance.

Comment: any solutions for my problem though ? I could upload a photo of my python intepreter where it says what version I'm using, if you still don't believe me.

Comment: and @MadPhysicist did I provide all the info you asked for ? Thanks for your hepl btw!!

Comment: @hccavs19 I believe you, it's just windows I hesitate trusting :). Can you compare sys.path in both? I didn't completely understand what you said about sys.path in your question. I'm a little slow or ignorant maybe ;)

Comment: What both do you mean ? sys.path from the command line shows me where the packages get stored afer installation. For the pyinsane2 package it shows "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pyinsane2-2.0.2-py3.6-win32.egg" in the sys.path. No worries man, I appreciate your help a lot! Thanks !